# Extracting Month and year out of the numerical date string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date

I have a date string:

```
2014-04-7
```

and I would like to extract the month and year:

```
April 2014
```

out of it using Ruby.

I looked for a solution in here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_date_time.htm, but there's nothing that addresses my issue. Stackoverflow search did not locate a solution either (as far as I can tell).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Date.parse('2014-04-7').strftime("%B %Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do as below :

```
require 'date'

Date.strptime('2014-04-7','%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%B %Y')
# => "April 2014"
```

*Format directives* are well written in the doc - [`#strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime).